# Redirect to other HTML via onclick function on a SVG Element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I am trying to redirect to another HTML Page when i click on my svg element. Here is how i tried it.

```
 draw.rect(300, 250).move(1100, 200).attr ({ 
                fill: 'grey',
                stroke: '#000',
                'stroke-width': 3
                })
                .click(function() {
                   href="./index.html"
                })
```

Would apreciate some help

Comment: `draw.rect` is used for canvases, not SVG. Are you using some library ?

Comment: You probably want to do `window.location.href = './index.html'` in your `.click()` function, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the rect in a `<a>` element like so:

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg width="250" viewBox="-10 -10 320 220">
 <a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
  <rect width="300" height="200" fill="grey" stroke="#000" stroke-width="3" />
 </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is how it should be done. There is a reason hyperlinks exist in svg!